# subtract a range of cells to a single cell

Tags: excel, vba, range, with-statement

In my VBA code below it takes a start number in cell d1 takes another number in cell b5 then displays the result in cell d7. What I want to do is take a range of cells that subtract from the cell in d1. So right now it just takes cell b5 values. I want the range to go from b5-f5. So all of the cells in that range should subtract from cell d1 then the output is displayed in d7.

```
Sub Preform_Subtraction_Verion1()
    
    Dim CalcWS As Worksheet
    Dim StartingTotal As Double
    Dim DayTotal As Double
    
    Set CalcWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    With CalcWS
        StartingTotal = .Range("D1").Value
        DayTotal = .Range("B5").Value
        .Range("D7").Value = StartingTotal - DayTotal
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `DayTotal = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("B5:F5"))`

Comment: `.Range("D7").Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("B5:F5")) - (.Range("D1").Value * .Range("B5:F5").Columns.Count)`

Comment: @ScottCraner i tried copying this and it does not work

Comment: I assumed you wanted to take the value in D1 from each of the values not the total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this? Or do you need a separate output from each cell in range("B5:F5")?

```
Option Explicit
Sub Preform_Subtraction_Verion1()
    
    Dim CalcWS As Worksheet
    Dim StartingTotal As Double
    Dim DayTotal As Double
    
    Set CalcWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    With CalcWS
        StartingTotal = .Range("D1").Value
        DayTotal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("B5:F5"))
        .Range("D7").Value = StartingTotal - DayTotal
    End With
    
End Sub
```

[image: Example]